# how to create '\' before a sequence of numbers?

Tags: regex, shell

I have a mount of text files in a folder. Each file contains a sequence of numbers as:

```
  1
  1
  2 
  3 
  4 
  5
```

for the first file, and

```
  1
  7
  7 
  4 
  6 
  1
```

for the second file, and so on.
 now I want to copy all these text files into one new master file with each filename at the beginning of each part, one '.' at the end of each file, and one '\' before each number.I mean I wish the result to be like this:

```
#!MLF!#
*/faem0_si762.txt
\1
\1
\2 
\3 
\4 
\5
 .
*/fajw0_sx3.txt
\1
\7
\7 
\4 
\6 
\1
.
*/faem0_si1392.txt
.
.
.
```

I have written a piece of shell script to make it done,   But Im stuck in having the \ before numbers. Here is my code:

```
 #!/bin/sh

cd clusteredlabels_train
echo  "#!MLF!#";
for i in *;

do
     echo "\"*/$i\"";
     cat "$i";
     echo ".";
done
```

Anyone got an idea which part I should change? thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for example `sed` to insert a `\` before any line:

```
 #!/bin/sh

cd clusteredlabels_train
echo  "#!MLF!#";
for i in *;

do
     echo "\"*/$i\"";
     sed -r 's/^/\\/' "$i";
     echo ".";
done
```

Comment: I tried your solution as well, I receive this error: sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: Strange, works on my cygwin bash terminal ... There is no need of option `-r` here in fact, should work without it.

Comment: anyway, thank you for taking the time, my problem is solved now :))

Comment: @KianStar Indeed, under MacOs things may be different!

Comment: I removed the -r flag  and now its working perfectly! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line in your script

```
cat "$i";
```

with

```
sed -r 's/^([[:digit:]]+)/\\\1/' "$i"
```

#### Description

```
s/^([[:digit:]]+)/\\\1/
```

We ask `sed` to find at the beginning of a line (`^`) one or more digit (`[[:digit:]]+`). Then we ask it to rewrite those digits (`\0`) by preceding them with a backslash (`\\`).

**Tested on** *Windows 7 - cygwin 2.852(64 bit) - sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2*

Comment: No need to `cat` and pipe, `sed` takes file names after the command string.

Comment: Thank you, by numbers.txt you mean *.txt? I tried your solution right now, but it stops at sed line.

Comment: Thank you 10000 times @Stephan, I changed your idea slightly to get what I want, from s/^[[:digit:]+]/\\\0/     to      s/^[[:digit:]+]/\\/  (no need for \0 at the end)

Comment: Ohhh wait a moment, now every number is lost its first digit! for first file, for example, 93 is changed to \3 . Do you know why this happened?

Comment: @KianStar This happened because there is no `\0`

Comment: @Stephan The pattern space is `&` in `sed`, not `\0`. This latter is not a back reference on anything (`sed` limits back references to `\1` to `\9`). See this [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) and this [page](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-3) for confirmation.

Comment: @Bentoy13 On my cygwin box, it worked fine. However, I updated my answer to make things clearer.

Comment: @Stephan Indeed, quite strange, I don't find it on the web, but yeah it works on mine too. Sorry, I've two other remarks on your solution. First, the grouping parentheses are missing on the first code line beginning by `sed`. Second, the `+` is inside the character class group (inside the outtermost square brackets), so your search regexp is "find at the line beginning a digit or a `+`". No impact on the result here, so your solution is working, but  deeply not the way you think.